# easy jQuery - php communication

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, interface

i'm working on an php-application, and now i have to build an interface to communicate between jquery and php. i already have a working controller/action. what is the best way to communicate with jQuery, if i need to send an array to php in the request.

example:
data that is needed to fulfill the request:

```
$request_data = array 
(
  'key1' => 'value1',
  'list1' => array
  (
    'listkey1' => 'listvalue1',

  )
)
```

should i send this in different as "normal" post-request, or is it easier to send one post-var with the array encoded in json? ($post_json="{key: value....})

the focus is on easy integration in jquery

edit: it is not about passing the data to the client, it is about passing the array from the client to the php-script

Comment: well you tagged the question with ajax, so use ajax ?

Comment: yes, it is a form, with dynamic elements. if the user uses a dropdown, the dropdown should be dynamically updated based on other inputs before it is shown.

Comment: definitely sounds like a job for ajax.

Comment: my question is, what is the best way to pass the array to the php-script, as json in a single post-var or in multiple post-vars. or is an even better solution possible?

Answer (score 3):

use phps json_encode() to generate the response, and read it with jquery on client?

```
$.getJSON('youpage.php', function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    alert(key + '=>' + value);
  });
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

UPDATE

in regards to communication the other way, from the client to php. It all depends on the task at hand really. If the data in the drop down purely depend on the entries on the form, and they are otherwise stateless. Then,the best route will depends on your backend code, you could do a ajax post, with the individual variables, or concatenate them into one variable before sending, and then splitting them up on the backend. Or, as you say, you could create a json string and then use json_decode on the backend.

Which route is fit for purpose depends on many factors, and I dont think there is a right or wrong error.

Personally, I would generate a AJAX post request (im not a php coder though) to the backend, and then process the request object directly.  You still would need to process a data structure, so why add the overhead/extra-step of deserializing json from the request.

Comment: the response is already json-encoded, i just don't know how to pass array-like information from js to php with the ajax-request. sorry about the confusion

Comment: is there a problem with passing arrays in ajax posts?

Comment: Just post the JSON string in a single POST variable to the server? Why not, it's the simplest solution, especially for e.g. multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: OK, it is working now, i used the $.post method to use ajax-posts, it is quite simple. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery post

```
$.post('url', data, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

YOu can access the data in php

```
echo $_POST['key1'];
echo $_POST['key2'];
```

Comment: hm, i think i have learn more about ajax/js/jquery. i think i have absolutely no idea what i'm doing ;-) thanks all

Comment: thanks for the link, a good starting point for testing the ajax post request :-)